# runing the macro automatically to all existing and new documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have macro that create the footer with author and date, but I need this macro to automatically run to all word document (existing and the new document) just I open the word file which I saved before or the new one so there we find in document the macro that I create

Answer (score 1):

save your macro file as a word addin file or put your macro in your personal.doc file and will be available for all files.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in ThisDocument as OnCreate method ("Private Sub Document_NewDocument" if I remember well). Save it as Normal.dotm template, so it will automatically call it created document. You can also store it as OnOpen, and start your macro from removeing footer - this way all documents you open will get your footer.